# AWS: Does elastic beanstalk use s3 (storage) implicitly?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-s3

I'm very new to AWS (today is the second day of my free trial). I've created elastic beanstalk application (using Tomcat server) and deployed very simple java web-app (1 static page & 1 jsp generated by servlet). I'm not using any AWS api or so on, just upload war file to EB project. When I see my statistic there is S3 - Puts and S3 - Gets usage.

[image: AWS usage 1]
[image: AWS usage 2]

Between this screenshots I've just once opened my web-app, but S3 usage still growing(:

How to know where my application use S3, and how to prevent this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk stores application deployment artifacts on S3. Elastic Beanstalk also archives application logs to S3. It should be extremely easy for you to open the S3 console and look at the S3 buckets and objects in your account to see what is going on.